# Jquery Form Plugin: how to show progress bar only when form has enctype tag

Tags: forms, jquery-plugins

I'm using Jquery Form Plugin to submit data via Ajax and I've no problem.
I also implemented the progress bar successfully.

I wish to show progress bar only when the form has the tag enctype="multipart/form-data", but I've problem to read form attributes inside AjaxForm object:

```
$('.form_to_main').ajaxForm({
    delegation: true,
    target: '#main_content',
    beforeSend: function(arr, myform, options) {
      _is_loading = true;
      $('#loading').fadeIn();
      //here something like if($(myform).attr("enctype") != '')
      $('#loading .progress_bar .bar_container .bar').width('0%')
      $('#loading .progress_bar .percent').html('0%');
      //else $('#loading .progress_bar).hide();
    },
    beforeSubmit: function() {
      if (_is_loading) return false;
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
      $('#loading .progress_bar .bar_container .bar').width(percentComplete + '%')
      $('#loading .progress_bar .percent').html(percentComplete + '%');
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      BoxErrorShow('Connection error: ' + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
      $('#loading').hide();
      _is_loading = false;
    },
    success: function() {
      $('#loading .progress_bar .bar_container .bar').width('100%')
      $('#loading .progress_bar .percent').html('100%');
      $('#loading').hide();
      _is_loading = false;          
    }
  });
});
```

In the beforeSend: method I want to check the enctype attribute, but it's not clear to me ho to access to form object.

Thanks for the support

UPDATE - SOLVED
I use the beforeSubmit parameters in beforeSend function.
So the correct code is the following:

```
$('.form_to_main').ajaxForm({
    delegation: true,
    target: '#main_content',
    beforeSend: function() {
      _is_loading = true;
      $('#loading').fadeIn();
      $('#loading .progress_bar .bar_container .bar').width('0%')
      $('#loading .progress_bar .percent').html('0%');
    },
    beforeSubmit: function(arr, myform, options) {
      if ($(myform).attr("enctype") == 'multipart/form-data') $('#loading .progress_bar').show();
      if (_is_loading) return false;
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
      $('#loading .progress_bar .bar_container .bar').width(percentComplete + '%')
      $('#loading .progress_bar .percent').html(percentComplete + '%');
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      BoxErrorShow('Connection error: ' + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
      $('#loading').hide();
      _is_loading = false;
    },
    success: function() {
      $('#loading .progress_bar .bar_container .bar').width('100%')
      $('#loading .progress_bar .percent').html('100%');
      $('#loading .progress_bar').hide();
      $('#loading').hide();
      _is_loading = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED I use the beforeSubmit parameters in beforeSend function.
See the answer for details.